# Remove width attribute from css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

Is there any way to `remove width attribute` present in css class using jquery or javascript.

```
table.searchlistTable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Note**: Is there any other solution instead of below.

```
$("table.searchlistTable").removeClass("searchlistTable");
$("table.searchlistTable").addClass("xyz");
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don`t think it is possible to remove attribute from the class. You can remove either the whole class or simply attribute from the element.

Comment: why would you do that. Set the `width` attribute value to `auto` instead.

Comment: @madforstrength, attribute from the element means from inline css?

Comment: @NamanGala Why cant you use `$(elem).css('width','auto');` ?

Comment: @NamanGala  yes thats what i mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update style class any property won't feasible, but you could overwrite style any property using jquery `css()` function, it would also work in same manner, for instance you want to remove `width` then you can use `auto` property, see below sample code

```
 $("table.searchlistTable").css("width", 'auto');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".searchlistTable").css('width' , 'auto')
```

or

```
$(".searchlistTable").css('width' , 'initial')
```

[Safe CSS Defaults](http://nimbupani.com/safe-css-defaults.html)
[The inherit, initial, and unset values](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cascading/values.html)